# Error while sending JMS(message) with jboss EAP 7

Tags: java, jms, ejb, stateless-session

Using Wildfly and JMS via ActiveMQ I got following exception.

> javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Producer is closed

I have the following stateless bean

```
@Stateless(name = "ExchangeSenderFacadeBean")
@Local({ExchangeSenderFacadeLocalI.class})
public class ExchangeSenderFacadeWrapperBean implements ExchangeSenderFacadeLocalI {
    @Resource(lookup = "java:/JmsXA")     // inject ConnectionFactory (more)
    protected ConnectionFactory factory;

    @EJB(beanName = "BeanRegistryLoader")
    protected BeanRegistryLoader omsRegistryBean;

    protected BeanRegistryCore beanRegistryCore;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/queue/ToExchange")
    protected Queue target;

    private ExchangeSenderFacadeCoreI exchangeSenderFacadeCore;


    @Override
    public void sendToExchange(ExchangeMessage exchangeMessage) {
        exchangeSenderFacadeCore.sendToExchange(exchangeMessage);

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        beanRegistryCore = omsRegistryBean.registry();
        if (exchangeSenderFacadeCore == null) {
            exchangeSenderFacadeCore = ((BeanRegistryCore) omsRegistryBean.registry()).getExchangeSenderFacadeCoreI();
            exchangeSenderFacadeCore.setBeanRegistryCore(omsRegistryBean.registry());
            exchangeSenderFacadeCore.setFactory(factory);
            exchangeSenderFacadeCore.setTargetQueue(target);
        }
    }

}
```

And I use simple java class to create a method which produces a message and send it to the destination as follow

```
public class ExchangeSenderFacadeCore implements ExchangeSenderFacadeCoreI {
    private static final OMSLogHandlerI logger = new Log4j2HndlAdaptor("ExchangeSenderFacadeCore");
    private BeanRegistryCore beanRegistryCore;
    private ConnectionFactory factory;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Session session = null;
    private long ttl = 900000;
    protected Queue targetQueue;

    public ExchangeSenderFacadeCore() {
        if (System.getProperty(OMSConst.SYS_PROPERTY_JMS_TTL) != null && System.getProperty(OMSConst.SYS_PROPERTY_JMS_TTL).length() > 0) {
            ttl = Long.parseLong(System.getProperty(OMSConst.SYS_PROPERTY_JMS_TTL));
        }
        logger.info("LN:103", "==JMS Topic TTL:" + ttl);
    }

    @Override
    public void processSendToExchange(ExchangeMessage exchangeMessage) {
        sendToExchange(exchangeMessage);
    }

    public boolean isParallelRunEnabled() {
        Object isParallelRun = beanRegistryCore.getCacheAdaptorI().cacheGet(OMSConst.DEFAULT_TENANCY_CODE, OMSConst.APP_PARAM_IS_PARALLEL_RUN, CACHE_NAMES.SYS_PARAMS_CACHE_CORE);
        if (isParallelRun != null && String.valueOf(isParallelRun).equals(OMSConst.STRING_1)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendToExchange(ExchangeMessage exchangeMessage) {
        MessageProducer producer = null;
        try {
            if (isParallelRunEnabled()) {
                logger.info("LN:66", "== Message send to exchange skipped,due to parallel run enabled");
                return;
            }
            if (connection == null) {
                connection = factory.createConnection();
            }
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            producer = session.createProducer(targetQueue);
            producer.setDisableMessageID(true);
            Message message = beanRegistryCore.getJmsExchangeMsgTransformerI().transformToJMSMessage(session, exchangeMessage);
            producer.send(message);
            producer.setTimeToLive(ttl);//default 15min
            logger.elkLog("78", "-1", LogEventsEnum.SENT_TO_EXCHANGE, exchangeMessage.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("LN:80", " Error when sending order to exchange:", e);
            throw new OMSCoreRuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (producer != null)
                    producer.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.error("LN:87", "JMS producer close error:", e);
            }
            try {
                if (session != null)
                    session.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.error("LN:93", "JMS session close error:", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void processSendToExchangeSync(ExchangeMessage exchangeMessage) {

    }

    @Override
    public BeanRegistryCore getBeanRegistryCore() {
        return beanRegistryCore;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanRegistryCore(BeanRegistryCore beanRegistryCore) {
        this.beanRegistryCore = beanRegistryCore;
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFactory(ConnectionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    public Queue getTargetQueue() {
        return targetQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTargetQueue(Queue targetQueue) {
        this.targetQueue = targetQueue;
    }
}
```

`ExchangeSenderFacadeCoreI` is interface class but when I execute this code I get above exception but if I move `sendToExchange()` method in `ExchangeSenderFacadeCore` to `ExchangeSenderFacadeWrapperBean` class then the error will disappear. Can anyone tell me the exact reason for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

After a deep search deep into the problem, I found this
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ShouldICacheJMSConnectionsAndJMSSessions article posted on one of JBOSS developer thread. This explains clearly the reason for caching connection and other JMS related resources being an anti-pattern for JMS code is running in a JEE application server.

In nutshell JCA layer pools JMS connections and JMS sessions. So when you call `createConnection()` or `createSession()`, then, in most cases it's not really calling the actual JMS implementation to actually create a new JMS connection or JMS session, it's just returning one from its own internal cache.

Additionally JBOSS server too manages stateless session bean pool. A stateless session bean is available on the connection pool only after you are done with the purpose of it, but not prior. Meantime Connection (Either JMS newly created or Cached) used to create `JMS Session (session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE))` inside stateless session bean,  also done with its purpose and too available on JCA layer connection pool. Therefore calling cached connection inside stateless EJB class as follow will not give you an exception even though it is not recommended by Oracle.

```
public void sendToExchange(ExchangeMessage exchangeMessage) {
        MessageProducer producer = null;
        try {
            if (isParallelRunEnabled()) {
                logger.info("LN:66", "== Message send to exchange skipped,due to parallel run enabled");
                return;
            }
            if (connection == null) {
                connection = factory.createConnection();
            }
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            producer = session.createProducer(targetQueue);
            producer.setDisableMessageID(true);
            Message message = beanRegistryCore.getJmsExchangeMsgTransformerI().transformToJMSMessage(session, exchangeMessage);
            producer.send(message);
            producer.setTimeToLive(ttl);//default 15min
            logger.elkLog("78", "-1", LogEventsEnum.SENT_TO_EXCHANGE, exchangeMessage.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("LN:80", " Error when sending order to exchange:", e);
            throw new OMSCoreRuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (producer != null)
                    producer.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.error("LN:87", "JMS producer close error:", e);
            }
            try {
                if (session != null)
                    session.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.error("LN:93", "JMS session close error:", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

But in this case, since the same POJO class instance can be used on multiple occasions as bellow. It does not guarantee that connection is freed and available in the JCA layer connection pool and gives exceptions.

```
   @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        beanRegistryCore = omsRegistryBean.registry();
        if (exchangeSenderFacadeCore == null) {
            exchangeSenderFacadeCore = ((BeanRegistryCore) omsRegistryBean.registry()).getExchangeSenderFacadeCoreI();
            exchangeSenderFacadeCore.setBeanRegistryCore(omsRegistryBean.registry());
            exchangeSenderFacadeCore.setFactory(factory);
            exchangeSenderFacadeCore.setTargetQueue(target);
        }
    }
```